# How do I set condition for printf to print only specific item's data out of file

Tags: c, struct, text-files

If the file store a multiple items set, how do I set a condition for printf to print only specific item's data out of file. what I was thinking is input the item's ID, if the ID that input match the ID of item in file then printf item's data but `if (t.id==id)` did not work.

```
display after scanf ID = 1
ID  Name        Quantity Price
1   Car Battery 3        89
2   Watch       3        34
.
.
.
(all the item form file)
```

```
what I expect after scanf ID = 1

ID  Name        Quantity Price
1   Car Battery 3        89
```

```
struct Product
{
    int id;
    char name[40];
    int price;
    int qty;
    int buy;
};

void generateBill();

char fproduct[]= {"product.dat"};
int total = 0, buys;
```

```
void generateBill()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct Product t;
    int count = 0, id, found = 0 ,Receive, totalmoney = 0;

    fp=fopen(fproduct,"rb");
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Enter ID of item that want to display: ");
    scanf("%d",&id);

    while(1)
    {
        fread(&t,sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (t.id==id)                       //condition to print a only specific item's data
        printf("%d",t.id);
        printf("%s\t", t.name);
        printf("%d\t",buys);
        printf("%d\n", t.price);
        totalmoney = (buys*t.price);

        count = count + buys;
        total = total + totalmoney;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: `if (t.id == id) printf("%d%s\t%\t%d\n", t.id, t.name, buys, t.price);` or put the 4 prints inside a block.

Answer (score 0):

You need a block (parentheses) around the print-statements in the `if`:

```
   if (t.id==id) {
     printf("%d",t.id);
     printf("%s\t", t.name);
     printf("%d\t",buys);
     printf("%d\n", t.price);
   }
```

Otherwise, only one statement (i.e. `printf("%d",t.id);`)  will be conditional, and all the others will print all the time.

Further, you could think of a `break` once the id of interest has been found (no need then to read to the end of the file, right?)

Comment: what if the id value was scanf in the previous function, does the value still tranfer to this function to make a condition if ? or Do I need to change condition in if